# calling a jQuery function named in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have several jQuery function like 
`function setOne();
setTwo(); setThree();`

and a variable `var number` that values respectively "one", "two", "three".

How can I call function "setOne()" when number values "one", function "setTwo" when number values "two" and so on...?

Thank you so much in advance. Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Looks like normal JavaScript functions to me.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you have your function in the global scope (on the window object) you can do:

```
// calls function setOne, setTwo, ... depending on number.
window["set" + number]();
```

And using `eval` will allow you to run functions in local scope:

```
eval("set" + number + "()");
```

[When is JavaScript's `eval()` *not* evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

Comment: Best answer, I accept this, simple and helpful and you know exactly what I mean! Thank you! If you you want you can vote my question.

Comment: `this["set" + number]();` would not work. Only if `setX` is a property of whatever `this` refers to, but not if `setX` is a local variable.

Comment: Sorry, but if `number` is exactly as bobighorus describes (e.g. `one`, `two`, `three`) then this will give an error, as `setone` != `setOne`?!

Comment: @AndreasAL Ah, thanks! ;)  Then why not copy that part from my answer so we'll have it in the accepted answer too :)

Comment: Great ! Congratulations

Answer (score 8):

Create a `name -> function` map:

```
var funcs = {
    'one': setOne,
    'two': setTwo
    /*...*/
};
```

Then you call the function with:

```
funcs[number]();
```

Comment: Actually AndreasAL's answer is the better one. People need to understand that in JavaScript everything is a dictionary and even functions are only entries on the global scope dictionary that you can access in that way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Felix, but it seems like a switch iteration. I need an automatic solution like set+number+() that means setOne(); . I hope I was clear.

Comment: @Tigraine: It only works if the functions are global which in general is not a good idea (global namespace pollution).

Comment: @bobighorus: Well, you can also assign the functions directly to the object instead of defining them beforehand. Whether you do `function setOne() {...};` or `funcs['one'] = function() {...};` should not make a big difference. The advantage is that your code has a cleaner structure and is easier to understand.

Comment: @Felix Kling: You can still declare the functions on a deeper scope and use the this[] notation as AndreasAL suggested..

Comment: @Tigraine: That won't work. Only in global scope `this` refers to `window`, but you can never access local variables through `this`.

Comment: @Felix Kling: You can simply do so by setting this through `.call` but you get into trouble as `function <name>()` are only seen as local variables inside functions.. Best I could come up is similar to your approach: http://jsfiddle.net/85YSX/

Answer (score 8):

If the variable details the actual name of the JQuery function and you want to apply the function to a DOM element like 'body', you can do the following:

```
 $('body')['function-name']('params');
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided your functions are in the global scope, try:

```
function setOne() {
  console.log('setOne called');
}
function setTwo() {
  console.log('setTwo called');
}
function setThree() {
  console.log('setThree called');
}

var number, funcName;

number = 'one';
funcName = 'set' + number.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + number.slice(1);
window[funcName](); // output: setOne called

number = 'two';
funcName = 'set' + number.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + number.slice(1);
window[funcName](); // output: setTwo called

number = 'three';
funcName = 'set' + number.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + number.slice(1);
window[funcName](); // output: setThree called
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this is:

```
function hello(){
    alert("hello");
}
var str = "hello";
eval(str+"()");
```

Comment: Yeah but I have to call a function!

Comment: @bobighorus This calls the function hello()... use `var str = "One";` `eval("set" + str + "()");` for your example. You can even set *named parameters* this way... `eval("set" + str + "(parameterName)");`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have three functions for that?

```
var number;
function setNumber(n) {
    number = n;
}
```

`setNumber(1)` will set number to 1

`setNumber(2)` will set number to 2

ect

Comment: Thanks for yuou answer, but I think that you don't understand my question...:)

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Andreas answer, the following illustrates the approach when not using a global.

Make a variable that holds a set of functions:

```
var callbacks = {
    setOne: function(params) {
        // ...
    },
    setTwo: function(params) {
        // ...
    },
};
```

Then if you have a variable holding the function name, you can do:

```
var number = "Two";
callbacks["set" + number](params);
```