# Using a variable value to call an array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string variable which contains the name of an array.  What I'd like to do is access an element of that array.  And write it to another variable.  How can I do this?

```
var sample = new Array();
sample[0] = 'one';
sample[1] = 'two';

var arrayname = "sample";
var number = arrayname[1];  ///  Something like this, although I realize this doesn't work for obvious reasons...
```

I've read other questions in regards to using an variable value as a function, but I didn't understand the approach or even if this would work for the above situation.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588307/calling-a-jquery-function-named-in-a-variable/8588392#8588392

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
    var sample = new Array();
    sample[0] = 'one';
    sample[1] = 'two';

    var arrayname = "sample";
    var number = window[arrayname][1];
    alert(number);
```

Comment: But only if you run it in window scope, not inside a function.

Comment: definitely...as far as I know, if you created a local variable within a function, there is no way to get it with just a string name.  If a JS Super Guru can show me otherwise, I'd really like to know!!

Answer (score 2):

There's no universal way in JavaScript to do *exactly* what you've got set up there, but you *can* use string variables to access object properties in a dynamic way.

```
var objArr = { array1: [], array2: [] };
```

Now you can use a variable with the value "array1" or "array2" to get at those arrays:

```
var name = "array2";
objArr[name].push(14);
```

What you *cannot* do in JavaScript is access local variables by a dynamic name, or indirectly if you prefer.  You can access *global* variables that way if you have a name for the global context, which in a browser is the `window` object:

```
window[ name ].push(17);
```

However there's no way to get a similar name for a local scope.

*edit* — @Neal points out (and is downvoted mercilessly) that `eval()` can do what you want, but a lot of people recommend staying far away from `eval()` unless it's absolutely unavoidable (which is really rare). I've trained myself to ignore it so well that I always forget about it when questions like this are asked (which is, oddly, quite often on SO, though in my programming practice I never find myself wanting to do this).

Comment: Technically, eval should be able to do *exactly* what he wants but I perfectly understand why you wouldn't want to tell him that :)

Comment: @missingno as I said in my edit, I actually never think about `eval()` so I simply forgot :-)

Comment: @Pointy i even said in my post that it was **not** the best approach. I should have bolded it :-P

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
var arrayName = "sample",
    number = window[arrayname][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean you can use eval, but it is not the best approach:

```
eval("var arrayname = sample");
var number = arrayname[1];
```

Why not just do:

```
var arrayname = sample;
var number = arrayname[1];
```

Comment: I don't like `eval()` any more than anybody else but this doesn't really deserve a downvote; it's technically correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the global scope, you can access your array by doing

```
var sample = new Array();
sample[0] = 'one';
sample[1] = 'two';
var arrayname = "sample";
var number = (window[arrayname])[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sample = new Array();
sample[0] = 'one';
sample[1] = 'two';
var obj = {"sample": sample}

var arrayname = "sample";
var number = obj[arrayname][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of my head...

First declare some global variable

```
var buf;
```

Then

```
var sample = new Array();
sample[0] = 'one';
sample[1] = 'two';

var arrayname = "sample";
eval('buf=' + arrayname + ';');
var number = buf[1];
```

Damn undesirable way but does what you want...