# Dynamically call javascript function based on function arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, jquery-events

I have  a jQuery function which accepts few arguments  based on the argument I should call another jQuery function.

example:

```
arg0 = "Launch"
        arg1 = "menu"
```

example:

```
(function($)
 {
    preRender: function(arg0,arg1)
    {
        var nextFuncName = arg0+arg1; //launchmenu
        nextFuncName() // hope to call the function name framed from the number of arguments
     }
})(jQuery);

 (function($)
 {
    launchmenu: function()
     {
       console.log("Launchmenu called");
     }
})(jQuery);
```

I referred the following link [calling a jQuery function named in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588307/calling-a-jquery-function-named-in-a-variable) but I don't  want to use `eval()` or window object.

Is it possible  to use `$.proxy` or any other method to achieve this functionality, also is it possible to achieve this using underscore.js?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can only do this if the full set of possible functions is defined as properties of some object, `myObject`. Then you can write `myObject[arg0 + arg1]()`.

Comment: Why is each of your functions defined in a separate immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) that takes jQuery as an argument? And by a "jQuery function" do you mean such a function defined inside an IIFE, or do you actually mean a method of the jQuery library?

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `jQuery` object

> …or much better an own, local object, instead of polluting the global
>   jQuery namespace.

---

> Merge them so that you use `localObject` for `launchmenu` but `$` for `preRender`

---

```js
(function($) {

  var localObject = {};

  function launchmenu() {
    console.log("Launchmenu called")
  }

  function preRender(arg0, arg1) {
    var nextFuncName = arg0 + arg1;
    if (nextFuncName in localObject) {
      localObject[nextFuncName]()
    } else {
      console.log(typeof nextFuncName)
    }
  }


  localObject.launchmenu = launchmenu;
  $.preRender = preRender;
  
}(jQuery));

$(function() {
  $.preRender("launch", "menu");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: …or much better an own, local object, instead of polluting the global jQuery namespace.

Comment: Well there was nothing wrong with exporting `preRender` to `$`, only all those dynamically-named function should stay inside the IIFE.

Comment: @Bergi When defining outside IIFE , as named function , attempt is to preserve ability to utilize outside of "local object" , or jQuery - though would change the `$` within `if` condition to `this` , so call, apply could be utilized ; without redefining `$` before, when called. Not certain interpreting _"only all those dynamically-named function should stay inside the IIFE."_ portion correctly ? Can describe details ?

Comment: @Bergi What could be improved at above solutions ?

Comment: Just what I said: Merge them so that you use `localObject` for `launchmenu` but `$` for `preRender `.