# How to change animation name/type in jquery by a string name

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadeout, slideup

This is the concept. what is the possible way to do this
Here my code:

```
var animationName='slideUp';
if(true){
animationName='fadeOut';
}

$('.className').animationName(200,function(){
     //callback
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling a jQuery function named in a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588307/calling-a-jquery-function-named-in-a-variable) Hope this link will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to execute string as javascript expression. In `eval()` you can use variable as function name.

```js
var animationName = "slideUp";
eval("$('div')."+ animationName +"(200, function(){})");
```

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```